# what is the advantage of using a CPU register for temporarydata storage over using a memory location?

Tags: cpu-registers, microprocessors

what is the advantage of using a CPU register for temporary data storage over using a memory location ?

Comment: It's very much faster to access it?

Comment: It is also more secure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- registers are accessed usually in 1 cpu cycle (.3 nano-seconds).
- L1
  Cache access is .5 nano-seconds
- L2 cache access is 7 nano-seconds
- DRAM access is 200 nano-seconds.

So you are about 600x faster with registers than working with ram.

Speeds referenced from [here](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/04/21/storage_approaches_memory_speed_with_xpoint_and_storageclass_memory/).